# Android RecyclerView adapter items refresh

Tags: android

I am having a problem with the RecyclerView and the RecyclerView.Adapter. I got a function that sets a list of items into the adapter. When user swipe-to-refresh, I load fresh data which means some items are new, then I set the items into adapter and I have to invalidate them. My problem is with `notifyItemRangeInserted()` and `notifyItemRangeChanged()`. When new items appear, if I first remove them,  then `notifyItemRangeRemoved()`, then add and finally call `notifyItemRangeInserted()` it would work, but all items are invalidated and it blinks. Otherwise, if I determine the diff in size between new and old data set, it is not invalidating the proper elements.

```
public void setItems(@NonNull List<ItemType> items) {
        final int oldSize = mItems.size();
        mItems.clear();
        notifyItemRangeRemoved(firstPosition(), oldSize);
        mItems.addAll(items);
        notifyItemRangeInserted(firstPosition(), items.size());
}
```

`mItems` is ArrayList.

Comment: what's `firstPosition` ?\

Comment: firstPosition() is checking if the adapter has header. If header is present, it will be 1 otherwise 0. I solved this current problem by doing `notifyItemRangeInserted(firstPosition(), oldSize);` but the problem to update only a tiny chunk of items ain't solved without first removing the old items, then apply new ones. That way the blinking will be present, but that's acceptable for my current solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution was to use `hasStableIds()` in the adapter so the adapter can find out which items are changed.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this one ?

myRecycleAdapter.notifyItemInserted(items.size());

Your method would looks like below:

```
public void setItems(@NonNull List<ItemType> items) {
   mItems.clear();
   mItems.addAll(items);
   myRecycleAdapter.notifyItemInserted(items.size());
```

}

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you are overthinking the situation.

Similar to Hiren's answer, you can just:

```
public void setItems(@NonNull List<ItemType> items) {
   mItems.clear(); 
   mItems.addAll(items);
   myRecycleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); }
```

NotifyDataSetChanged will neither cause the blinking effect nor more your list from its current position.